# Barcode scanning issue

Tags: android

I am working on barcode scanning on button click to increment the quantity counted field by one of a table when the scanning result matches with the item number field of the table. If the scan result matches item number it should update the quantity counted of that row. I am unable to get the scan result itself. Getting `NullPointerException`.

This is my code.

These are two Java files from zxing.

IntentIntegrator.java

```
package com.example.mis;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class IntentIntegrator {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16
                                                    // bits
private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
private static final String BSPLUS_PACKAGE = "com.srowen.bs.android";

// supported barcode formats
public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A",
        "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A",
        "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
        "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections
        .singleton("QR_CODE");
public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections
        .singleton("DATA_MATRIX");

public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

public static final List<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections
        .singletonList(BS_PACKAGE);
public static final List<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(BSPLUS_PACKAGE, // Barcode
                                                                            // Scanner+
        BSPLUS_PACKAGE + ".simple", // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
        BS_PACKAGE // Barcode Scanner
// What else supports this intent?
);

private final Activity activity;
private String title;
private String message;
private String buttonYes;
private String buttonNo;
private List<String> targetApplications;
private final Map<String, Object> moreExtras;

public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
    buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
    targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
    moreExtras = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
    title = activity.getString(titleID);
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
    message = activity.getString(messageID);
}

public String getButtonYes() {
    return buttonYes;
}

public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
    this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
}

public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
    buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
}

public String getButtonNo() {
    return buttonNo;
}

public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
    this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
}

public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
    buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
}

public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
    return targetApplications;
}

public final void setTargetApplications(List<String> targetApplications) {
    if (targetApplications.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No target applications");
    }
    this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
}

public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
    this.targetApplications = Collections.singletonList(targetApplication);
}

public Map<String, ?> getMoreExtras() {
    return moreExtras;
}

public final void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
    moreExtras.put(key, value);
}

/**
 * Initiates a scan for all known barcode types.
 */
public final AlertDialog initiateScan() {
    return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
}

/**
 * Initiates a scan only for a certain set of barcode types, given as
 * strings corresponding to their names in ZXing's {@code BarcodeFormat}
 * class like "UPC_A". You can supply constants like
 * {@link #PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES} for example.
 * 
 * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them
 *         to download the app if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
 */
public final AlertDialog initiateScan(
        Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    // check which types of codes to scan for
    if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
        // set the desired barcode types
        StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
        for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
            if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
                joinedByComma.append(',');
            }
            joinedByComma.append(format);
        }
        intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
    }

    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
    startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
    return null;
}

/**
 * Start an activity. This method is defined to allow different methods of
 * activity starting for newer versions of Android and for compatibility
 * library.
 * 
 * @param intent
 *            Intent to start.
 * @param code
 *            Request code for the activity
 * @see android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
 * @see android.app.Fragment#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
 */
protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
}

private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (availableApps != null) {
        for (String targetApp : targetApplications) {
            if (contains(availableApps, targetApp)) {
                return targetApp;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean contains(Iterable<ResolveInfo> availableApps,
        String targetApp) {
    for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
        String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (targetApp.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String packageName = targetApplications.get(0);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                            + packageName);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    try {
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        // Hmm, market is not installed
                        Log.w(TAG,
                                "Google Play is not installed; cannot install "
                                        + packageName);
                    }
                }
            });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                }
            });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

/**
 * <p>
 * Call this from your {@link Activity}'s
 * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} method.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @return null if the event handled here was not related to this class, or
 *         else an {@link IntentResult} containing the result of the scan.
 *         If the user cancelled scanning, the fields will be null.
 */
public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode,
        int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
            int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra(
                    "SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null
                    : intentOrientation;
            String errorCorrectionLevel = intent
                    .getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
            return new IntentResult(contents, formatName, rawBytes,
                    orientation, errorCorrectionLevel);
        }
        return new IntentResult();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Defaults to type "TEXT_TYPE".
 * 
 * @see #shareText(CharSequence, CharSequence)
 */
public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text) {
    return shareText(text, "TEXT_TYPE");
}

/**
 * Shares the given text by encoding it as a barcode, such that another user
 * can scan the text off the screen of the device.
 * 
 * @param text
 *            the text string to encode as a barcode
 * @param type
 *            type of data to encode. See
 *            {@code com.google.zxing.client.android.Contents.Type}
 *            constants.
 * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them
 *         to download the app if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
 */
public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text, CharSequence type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intent);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    return null;
}

private static List<String> list(String... values) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values));
}

private void attachMoreExtras(Intent intent) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : moreExtras.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        // Kind of hacky
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Bundle) value);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra(key, value.toString());
        }
    }
}

}
```

IntentResult.java

```
 package com.example.mis;

 public class IntentResult {
 private final String contents;
  private final String formatName;
  private final byte[] rawBytes;
  private final Integer orientation;
  private final String errorCorrectionLevel;

  IntentResult() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  IntentResult(String contents,
               String formatName,
               byte[] rawBytes,
               Integer orientation,
               String errorCorrectionLevel) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
    this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
  }

  /**
   * @return raw content of barcode
   */
  public String getContents() {
    return contents;
  }

  /**
   * @return name of format, like "QR_CODE", "UPC_A". See {@code BarcodeFormat} for more format names.
   */
  public String getFormatName() {
    return formatName;
  }

  /**
   * @return raw bytes of the barcode content, if applicable, or null otherwise
   */
  public byte[] getRawBytes() {
    return rawBytes;
  }

  /**
   * @return rotation of the image, in degrees, which resulted in a successful scan. May be null.
   */
  public Integer getOrientation() {
    return orientation;
  }

  /**
   * @return name of the error correction level used in the barcode, if applicable
   */
  public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
    return errorCorrectionLevel;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
    dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
    int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
    dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
    dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
    return dialogText.toString();
  }

 }
```

This is the activity in which i am implementing barcode scanning

```
 public class InventoryCount extends Activity {

 private Button mbtn_scan;
 mbtn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(
                    InventoryCount.this);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
 }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // retrieve result of scanning - instantiate ZXing object
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
            requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    // check we have a valid result
    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Log.i("Scanning Result ", "" + scanningResult);
            Toast.makeText(
                    InventoryCount.this,
                    "Scanning success the content is : "
                            + scanningResult.getContents(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String sr = scanningResult.getContents();
            getBarCodeData(sr);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(InventoryCount.this,
                    "Scanning Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error on scanning: "+e);
    }

}

  public void getBarCodeData(String itmNumber) {

    Cursor c;
    try {

        String qtyCountQry = "SELECT " + DatabaseHandler.KEY_QTYCOUNTED
                + " FROM " + DatabaseHandler.TABLE_MIC2 + " WHERE "
                + DatabaseHandler.KEY_ITEMNUMBER + "='" + itmNumber + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase sq = db.getReadableDatabase();
        c = sq.rawQuery(qtyCountQry, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String q2 = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_QTYCOUNTED));
        Toast.makeText(InventoryCount.this, "Quantity Count is " + q2,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(InventoryCount.this, "Exception " + e,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I have just tried to display scan result and if it matches itemnumber it will display the corresponding quantity in that row as shown in code above. But as of now not even scan result is displaying. Help me.. Also say how to increment the quantity by one and update it in db.

Comment: At which line are you getting NPE??

Comment: Please always post Logcat when your app is forced closed.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: I am getting NPE after integrator.initiateScan();

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the zxing library by extending the CaptureActivity Class.

```
public class ScannerData extends CaptureActivity {
Handler handler = null;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
}
@Override
    public void handleDecode(final Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode,
            float scaleFactor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handler = getHandler();
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview,
                CaptureActivity.BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS);
        String mQrcode = rawResult.getText().toString();
}

}
```

Use the code like this.

You can get the qr-code here

> String mQrcode = rawResult.getText().toString();

In Xml you need to include capture.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="510dp"
            android:layout_height="310dp"
            android:background="@drawable/scanner_box"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="750dp"
                android:layout_height="450dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
                layout="@layout/capture" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```